# Block and unblock the label to edit by clicking: Ionic

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

[image]

I want something like as above shown image. When I click on the edit button then I should able to edit the label( A little about you label ) how can I do it.

```
<ion-item-divider>
      <ion-label>Summary</ion-label>
      <button ion-button clear item-end style="font-size:11px;color: #3BABE3;font-weight:bold;">Edit
        <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward" class="arrow"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-item-divider>

      <ion-item class="items">
        <p style="color:grey;font-size:11px;">A little about you</p>

      </ion-item>
```

The label should be blocked when I click on edit button it should be editable.

I'm assinging "A little about you" to a variable called summary.

```
<p style="color:grey;font-size:11px;">A little about you</p>
```

Actually this should be `<textarea>` instead of `<p>`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`contenteditale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) atribute.

```
<ion-item class="items">
    <p contenteditable="true" style="color:grey;font-size:11px;">A little about you</p>
</ion-item>
```

If you want to bind it to a variable you can do it like this:

```
<ion-item class="items">
    <p [attr.contenteditable]="editable" style="color:grey;font-size:11px;">A little about you</p>
</ion-item>
```

Where `editable` is a boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need / code example and after a while I realized that asking users to edit your ion-label inline of the same view is basically a bad UX.

Consider making that button "edit" of yours to just spawn an alert controller which will contain input field. This is how I did it below and in my case I did not have a special "edit" button - users could click on a title to change its name. But I think you will get the way you can do it in your case

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let set of sets; index as i">
    <button ion-button clear (click)="changeSetTitle( set.title, i)">
      <h2>{{ set.title }}</h2>
    </button>
    <p>{{ set.length }} items</p>
    <button ion-button icon-right clear item-end (click)="loadSetComponent(i)">
      Manage
      <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-item>
```

And in ts file:

```
changeSetTitle(currentTitle, index) {
    this.alertOn = true;
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Change name:',
      message: 'current: "'+currentTitle+'"',
      inputs: [
        {
          placeholder: 'type in a new name'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
            this.alertOn = false;
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Confirm',
          handler: data => {
            if (data[0].length === 0) {
              this.sets[index].title = currentTitle;
            } else {
              this.saveRequired = true;
              this.sets[index].title = data[0];
            }
            this.alertOn = false;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    // small trick to force focus onto alert (not working for iOS unfortunately.)
    alert.present().then(() => {
      const alertInput: any = document.querySelector('input.alert-input');
      alertInput.focus();
      return;
    });
  }
```